# extracting variable from multiple matlab files into one file

Tags: matlab

I have this project task, and I'm having problems solving it.
I took samples of the words from 1 to 10 spoken by 10 people.
From each sample I extracted each word e.g, I extracted the word 1 from all samples into different files. I now have 10 files each having the extracted first word. I want to combine these into one single array.

```
file = wavread( 'G:\Segmented Data\amir.wav');    
t = linspace(0,8,length(file));    
t2=linspace(0,.8,8820);    
section1 = file(1:8820,:);    
sound(section1, 11025);    
figure(1),    
plot(t2,section1);
```

I have 10 files having the above code. I want to extract the variable section from all these into a new file, and store them in an array.

Comment: fix your indentation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style. Also try clicking the 'code' button when you write your post to see tips on how to format. Due to the poor formatting people are unlikely to respond to this post.

Comment: @Shep: I've fixed the indentation. It's still not syntactically correct (what's that comma doing after `figure(1)`?) but at least we can read it now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to [concatenate arrays](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html)?

```
>> a = 1.0:0.1:1.9    % your data, obtained from `wavread()`

a =

    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000    1.5000    1.6000    1.7000    1.8000    1.9000

>> b = 2.0:0.1:2.9    % your data, obtained from `wavread()`

b =

    2.0000    2.1000    2.2000    2.3000    2.4000    2.5000    2.6000    2.7000    2.8000    2.9000

>> c = 3.0:0.1:3.9    % your data, obtained from `wavread()`

c =

    3.0000    3.1000    3.2000    3.3000    3.4000    3.5000    3.6000    3.7000    3.8000    3.9000

>> combined = [a; b; c]    % a, b, and c in one array

combined =

    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000    1.5000    1.6000    1.7000    1.8000    1.9000
    2.0000    2.1000    2.2000    2.3000    2.4000    2.5000    2.6000    2.7000    2.8000    2.9000
    3.0000    3.1000    3.2000    3.3000    3.4000    3.5000    3.6000    3.7000    3.8000    3.9000
```

This will, of course, only work if `a`, `b` and `c` are the same number of columns wide. If they are different sizes, you will have to pad them out with zeros so that they *are* the same size.

Comment: yes tthis works.but the problem is that these arrays are in different m files, not in same..a is in file1.m and b is in file2.m i want to combine these in file3.m

Comment: @ shep ..ok i ll take care next time

Comment: @newbie: It doesn't matter that the data are in different files. You already know how to read data out of **one** file - just repeat that for as many times as you have files.

Comment: i did it.u have to make mat files of all the different files.and then u can load them without any errors of no such directory or file.